# Android: Fullscreen Image Slider with Swipe and Pinch Zoom Gestures

Tags: android, image, zooming, fullscreen, swipe

I'm trying to follow this example:

[Link to example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

He makes Fullscreen Image Slider with Swipe and Pinch Zoom Gestures. The problem is that the example includes pictures of the SDCard and want to collect pictures of the Assets folder. Could someone tell me I should change in the Utils class example to get it?

many thanks

```
public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths() {

    Log.e("", "paso");
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    File directory = new File(
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);

    if (directory.isDirectory()) {

        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

        if (listFiles.length > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

                String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

                if (IsSupportedFile(filePath)) {

                    filePaths.add(filePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    return filePaths;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get images from assets folder this way.

```
try 
{
 AssetManager am = getAssets();
 String list[] = am.list("");
 int files = yourimagelist.length;
 for(int i= 0;i<=files ; i++)
 {
  BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(am.open(list[positionHere]));
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  buf.close();
 }
 }   
catch (IOException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why?? what happen with this?

Comment: i have edit my code. i need change this method of sd to assets.

Comment: So this my post is related to assets not for SD card

Comment: If you do me a favor and download the sample code, you'll see that this code does not work

Comment: I want to implement the code example in my app. but I want to take pictures of assets and not the sd. so I need to know how to change that method and return an arrayList of assets