# how can we add pinchzoom with image slider in android programming

Tags: android

This is my code what should i do please solve my problem

1. image sliding
2. pinch zoom image

   package com.example.testgesture;

   ```
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.GestureDetector;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
   import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   // private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;
   private ViewSwitcher mViewSwitcher;
   private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

   int[] resources = {
           R.drawable.first,
           R.drawable.second/*,
           R.drawable.third,
           R.drawable.fourth,
           R.drawable.fifth,
           R.drawable.sixth*/
   };

   private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // Get the ViewFlipper
       mViewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher1);

       /*mViewSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
           @Override
           public View makeView() {
               ImageView imageView = new ImageView(GestureActivity.this);
               imageView.setImageResource(resources[0]);

               Log.d(TAG, "setFactory#makeView");

               return imageView;
           }
       });*/

       // Add all the images to the ViewFlipper
       for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
           ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
           imageView.setImageResource(resources[i]);
           mViewSwitcher.addView(imageView);
       }

       // Set in/out flipping animations
       //mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
       //mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fadeout);

       CustomGestureDetector customGestureDetector = new             CustomGestureDetector();
       mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, customGestureDetector);
   }

   class CustomGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
       @Override
       public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

           // Swipe left (next)
           if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {
               mViewSwitcher.setInAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.left_in)     mViewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(MainActivity.this,                                       R.anim.left_out);

               mViewSwitcher.showNext();
           }

           // Swipe right (previous)
           if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()) {
               mViewSwitcher.setInAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.right_in);
               mViewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.right_out);

               mViewSwitcher.showPrevious();
           }

           /*mViewSwitcher.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
               @Override
               public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Animation End");
                   Log.d(TAG, "Child Count: " + mViewSwitcher.getChildCount());
               }

               @Override
               public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

               }
           });*/

           return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Your problem ? What is the exact problem : "what should i do please solve my problem " ?

Comment: i just want pinch zooming on image slider what should i do

Comment: We solve problems and exchange our knowledge, we don't offer read-solutions otherwise you will truning in the black with ready mini-solutions all over your project. Do some research try some, and then when you face an ERROR which is a PROBLEM we can maybe help you out if anyone knows how to do so.

Comment: i just need any tutorial related that code that will help me. read my question on the top rather code.

Comment: Exactly we don't give tutorials but solve errors when you have already tried something.

Comment: Also this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453409/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures